# In jquery can custom functions pass elements as their parametr

Tags: jquery, function, parameters, element, custom-function

In jquery I'm trying to make custom function, which one of its parameters is an element. I didn't get any error message but it seems that element can't be passed.

```
$(function() {
    $('#boxtoggle').click(test('#box', 500));
});

function test(eleme, time) {
    eleme.slideToggle(time);
}
```

Comment: `$('#boxtoggle').click(() => test('#box', 500));`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery's slideToggle method, then you need to target element as an jquery object.

Currently you are using slideToggle method on a string, which should give you 'is not a function' error.

Solution:

```
function test(elem, time) {
    $(elem).slideToggle(time);
}
```